How to make grub retry a menuentry when that menuentry boot failed?
Situation: when a menuentry failed to boot, grub2 will go back to menu selection and waiting forever for the user choosing another menuentry. How to make grub retry boot the same menuentry without user input?
This is a server with PXE boot, which has a chance of boot failure because the network is not as stable as disk, and a retry will solve the issue, insteading of the annoying waitting "Pressure Enter to retry"
